# Lecture Notes and Textbooks

Tags: books, lecture-notes

When teaching a course based a text book, is using the proofs of theorems and examples from a text book considered reproducing the material from the textbook, while providing the study lecture notes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make sure that my lecture notes do not infringe on copyrights?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/93492/how-to-make-sure-that-my-lecture-notes-do-not-infringe-on-copyrights)

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  What sort of "using"?

Comment: By using I mean, for example in the lecture course suppose I have to use the proof that the author gives in the textbook and I want to follow it, in this case the one teaching wants to incorporate the proof that the author has given, say for an established theorem.

Answer (score 3):

A textbook is produced as “here is a tool to teach students or a class”, while a paper is produced as “this is the state of play of our work”.

The author of the textbook expects lecturers and students to use the material but if they quote it in lecture notes or an essay they then expect it to be correctly referenced.

Comment: +1 I generalised to lecturers and students, do revert if inappropriate

Comment: @user2768 it’s improved my answer thanks.